# jquery DataTables - change value of a cell not just display value

Tags: jquery, datatables

Using [DataTables](http://www.datatables.net) I want to change the value of the data before rendering the table. I used this:

```
"fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex ) {
    if ( aData[2] == "0" ){
        $('td:eq(1)', nRow).html( '<b>6</b>' );
    }
}
```

But I found that although I changed the displayed text to be 0 to 6, when I sort by the column it's still sorting by the data and not the displayed text.

Does anyone know how I can actually change the data in the cell so that when I sort it will correctly sort by 0-6?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to update the datatable, not html.

```
oTable.fnUpdate( newValue, rowPos, columnPos);
```

assuming `oTable` is a reference to the datatable.

Comment: Thanks I'll give it ago, I guess i need jeditable ti use fnUpdate, yeah?

Comment: you should not need to use jEditable, just use fnUpdate. jEditable itself is not doing anything special other than calling fnUpdate in the example.

Comment: fnUpdate isn't actually changing the DOM correct ? I changed the value, but when someone filters, the same rows are being udpated again. How would one change it so the changes become permanent.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably paste some more of your code, especially the sorting area.

It seems you're mixing up val() and html():

This will get you the input or cell value as in the value tag "value=?"

```
$("#currentRow").val()
```

This will get you the actual html (data) between the tag "<td>data</td>"

```
$("#currentRow").html()
```

Comment: Hi there

  "fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex ) {
   if ( aData[2] == "0" ){
    $('td:eq(1)', nRow).html( '<b >2</b>' );
               
                 nRow
   }else if ( aData[2] == "1" ){
      $('td:eq(1)', nRow).html( '<b >1</b>' );
                
   }else if ( aData[2] == "2" ){
       $('td:eq(1)', nRow).html( '<b>0</b>' );
 return nRow;
  },


what i am trying to achieve is reversing the priority got from the server data (6 high priority - 0 low priority) for the purposes of sorting by priority so ascending (0 high - 6 low).

many Thanks for your help

Comment: After the fnRowCallback I do this sorting to try and sort by the revised Best Match (priority)

 "aaSorting": [[ 2, "asc" ]],
  "aoColumns": [
   /*checkbox*/{ "bSortable": false },
   /*ID*/{"bVisible":    false },
   /*best match*/null,
   /*VenueName*/null,
   /*Distance*/null,
   /*Capacity*/null,
   /*MeetingRooms*/null,
   /*Bedrooms*/null,
   /*Suitability*/null
      ]});