# How to refresh datatable column data

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, export

I use data table plugin with table as data source. I have to change some column value via javascript when the user types in some numbers into an input (this input is part of the table too and I have to export this values to). It is working well but when I want to export the table the columns witch was changed with javascript is not displayed in the exported file.

I think the problem is that I have not refreshed the datatable plugin. Is this correct? If yes how do I refresh the datasource? If no what can be the problem and how can I solve it?

I tried the `refresh()` method (`var dataTableObject = $(this).parents('table').dataTable(); dataTableObject.refresh();`) and the `$(this).parents('table').dataTable()` but is not working.

Edit: Here is how do I change the cell value:

```
$item.find('input.quantity-coefficient').each(function (i, d) {
        $(d).off('change').on('change', function () {
            var multiplier = $(this).val();
            //var dataTableObject = $(this).parents('table').dataTable();

            $($(this).data("row-price-info-class")).each(function (i, d) {
                var priceContainer = $(d);
                var price = parseFloat(priceContainer.data('price-value'));

                var priceInfoRatioContainer = $(priceContainer.data("ratio-input-class"));
                if (multiplier * price == 0) {
                    priceInfoRatioContainer.closest("td").addClass("no-euro");
                    priceInfoRatioContainer.html(" ");
                } else {
                    priceInfoRatioContainer.closest("td").removeClass("no-euro");
                    priceInfoRatioContainer.html(localizeNumber(multiplier * price));
                }

            });
            //TODO redrow the data 
            $(this).parents('table').dataTable().fnDraw();;
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refresh the dataTable with `fnDraw()`. In your example:

```
$(this).parents('table').dataTable().fnDraw();
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply but this is not working. At least my column data are not in the exported file :(

Comment: I added it to the original post

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys but I think I found the solution in this post: [jquery DataTables - change value of a cell not just display value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3299280/jquery-datatables-change-value-of-a-cell-not-just-display-value)

When I tried it on the first time the problem was that I started the row numbering from 1 and not from 0.

So for the others who may have this issue to, I have to use something like this:

```
(this).parents('table').dataTable().fnUpdate("new value", 0, 2)
```

To update the cell value. Actually this is not what I asked because this is not refresh all the table, but this is a solution for me now.